# Remapping USB number keypad as text macros?

Tags: usb, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, autokey

I bought a USB numberpad with the idea of programming some Autokey macros onto it.

Using xev, however, I see that the system does not recognize any difference between its keys and those on my main board.

Is there any way of assigning separate keys to the numberic USB board so that I can assign macros there? If so, which programs do I need (xmodmap, etc)?

Could hardware such as this work (they all seem to be Windows-only)

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Expertkeys-EK-20-programmable-keypad-keyboard-x/dp/B00JR4WVMA/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1540900344&sr=8-9&keywords=programmable+keypad

Comment: I too have a USB Numpad and am interested in this answer. Did you ever come up with a solution for this?